# Decreasing the width of a paragraph for wider screens

Tags: html, css

I already did some research but I couldn't find an answer.
I would like my paragraph on the 'about page' to stop at a certain width when I exceed the browsers width. But when I apply a width or a max-width the paragraph just sticks to the left side of the page. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section>
        <img src="img/Florian.jpg" alt="Florian" class="profilephoto">
        <div class="aboutme">
            <h3 class="text-center">About</h3>
            <p class="text-center primary">Blablabla</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS Media queries?

Comment: I already thought of that. But which selector and value should I use? When I apply a width of 50%, the paragraph takes 50% of the whole page and does not stay centered.

Comment: So where do you want the paragraph to be?

Comment: It should remain in the center of the page and the line width should not exceed a certain width.

Comment: You can use `margin:auto` on the paragraph together with a width / max-width. That will center it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

> The paragraph should remain in the center of the page and the line width should not exceed a certain width.

You can use `margin:auto` on the paragraph together with a `width` / `max-width`. That will center it.

```
.aboutme p {
  max-width: 80%; /* or your chosen width */
  margin: auto;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/oezhfmLh/)